# How to store elements in 2d vector without knowing his width?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, 2d

I have a 1 dimensional vector

```
std::vector<int> vec1 = {4, 5, 6, 7};
```

and I want to store these elements in a 2 dimensional vector

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec2;
```

but vec2 can only have height 3 and I have in vec1 - 4 elements.

The output of vec2 should be:

```
4 7
5
6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I do not fully understand the question, but what I understood can be achieved by 1 simple for loop. Just take into account, that we have only 3 rows.

There is not much to explain . . .

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    // 1d vector with any number of values
    std::vector<int> vec1 = { 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    //2d vector with 3 rows
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec2(3);

    // Take all elements from vec1 and copy them to vec2, columns first
    for (size_t i{}; i < vec1.size(); ++i) 
        vec2[i % 3].push_back(vec1[i]);

    // Output
    for (const auto& v : vec2) {
        for (const auto& i : v) std::cout << i << "\t";
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to add an explanation for `vec2[i % 3].push_back(vec1[i]);`-

You can somehow think that the 2 dimensional `std::vector` consists of rows and columns. And a row contains again a `std::vector`, which contains the columns value.

So, if I want to use row 0, then I van write `vec[0]`. And if I want to add column values for row 0, then I can write `vec[0].push_back()`.

For row 1 and row 2 the similar approach applies. And since we want to distribute all values from "vec1" with index 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 . . . to rows with the numbers 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2 . . . we need to calculate the row number from the index of "vec1". And this can easily be done with the modulo division `%`

So:

```
0 % 3 = 0
1 % 3 = 1
2 % 3 = 2
3 % 3 = 0
4 % 3 = 1
5 % 3 = 2
6 % 3 = 0
7 % 3 = 1
. . .
```

That is all.

Comment: Can you please explain how does the for loop with vec2[i % 3] works?

Comment: @malicization `i%3` give you the remainder after diving `i` with 3. In the first iteration, `i = 0`, which means the expression is 0 % 3 which is 0. Second iteration, `1 % 3` which is 1. Third iteration 2 % 3 which is 2. Then `i` resets to 0 and it continues as 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2...